# Ajax form with jquery validation

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I can't make heads or tails of this and am wondering if you could help!   When I click on the button, nothing happens.  Ideally, I would like the form to validate before submission and to prevent submission if it doesn't validate.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/validate/jquery.validate.min.js">             
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/validate/jquery.validate.more.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 var J = jQuery.noConflict();

   J(document).ready(function(){ 

J("form#nameform").validate({
                    rules: {
                    "name": {
                    required: true,
                    format: true},
                },
                    submitHandler: function() {


        J.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: J("form#nameform").serialize(),  
             success: function(html) {
 J('form#nameform').html('hello');
  }  

 });            
    };
    }); 
});



 </script>


 <div id="name">  
 <form id="nameform" method="post">  
 <input id="name" class="text" name="name" size="20" type="text">  
 <input type="submit" value="go" />  
   </form>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A lot of [tutorial](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/) to make Jquery Form valitation, they show how to make ajax validation too :)